# Is there any faster way to hide/show html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a faster way to show/hide about 20000+ dom element.

I found that it is very slow using `element.style.display = "none"`

I think it's because I cause too many reflows of the browser.

But just `element.style.visibility = "hidden"` is not enough because the height of the element still exists

Is there any better way?

I can only use google closure

There is a runable example. But in my project, there are about 20000+ checkboxes

```js
function filter_change (txt) {
  var eles = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox_container");
  for (var i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
    var cnt = eles[i];
    var ipt = cnt.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    if (ipt.id.indexOf(txt.value) < 0) {
      cnt.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      cnt.style.display = "flex";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" onkeyup="filter_change(this)" />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" value="checkbox_1" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_1" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" value="checkbox_2" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_2" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_3" value="checkbox_3" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_3" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_4" value="checkbox_4" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_4" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_5" value="checkbox_5" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_5" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_10" value="checkbox_10" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_10" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_10</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_100" value="checkbox_100" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_100" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_100</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1000" value="checkbox_1000" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_1000" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_1000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_10000" value="checkbox_10000" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_10000" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_10000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_15000" value="checkbox_15000" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_15000" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_15000</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_20000" value="checkbox_20000" class="checkbox_input">
    <label for="checkbox_20000" class="checkbox_label">checkbox_20000</label>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], thanks.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery `$(selector).hide()`?

Comment: What libraries do you use ? What are the frameworks  you use ? Where is your code  ?

Comment: @zer00ne the example has been added, please check

Comment: Anything with 20k dom elements getting manipulated is going to be "slow"....

Comment: @AniketG I can not use or add jQuery libraries to the project

Comment: @prime I can only use google closure and javascript

Comment: @cale_b I agree, but I just hope that maybe there are some ways which can improve a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS:

```
.checkbox_container input[id*='15'] {
   display: none;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h47015x9/)

Or use CSS selector in your javascript code, and add class instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox_container input[id*="' + txt.value '"]')
   .forEach(el => el.classList.add('hidden'))
```

defining class 'hidden' as:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

**IMPORTANT**

With your javascript code, make sure you validate `txt.value` so that it only contains characters valid for a CSS class name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use 
```if (txt == null || txt.length == 0) {
        style.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        style.innerHTML = ".checkbox_container:not([title*='" + txt + "']) { display: none; }";
    }``` and it speeds up a little bit

Comment: @BabyCabbage - note that you [should not use `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/870729) (also known as the [evil twins]) in javascript.  Instead, use `===`....